# Filter duplicates on cross fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So, i have some records:

```
[ fid  sid ]
   1    2
   1    3
   1    4
   2    1
   2    3
   2    4
   3    1
   3    2
   3    4
    ....
```

Both fields contains ids. I need to get only uniq or first not-uniq records, but uniq by cross fields.
For example [2,1] and [1,2] are not uniq.

In the end i want to have:

```
[ fid  sid ]
   1    2
   1    3
   1    4
   2    3
   2    4
   3    4
    ....
```

Those are records, that have been filtered:

```
[ fid  sid ]
   2    1
   3    1
   3    2
    ....
```

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: If you have [2,1] and [1,2], how do you decide which one to keep?

Comment: @MrJF Not much, only played with joins.

Comment: @HoneyBadger first not-uniq record. The first appearence.

Comment: `First` is meaningless without order, what is the order? (Tables are inherently unsorted)

Comment: @HoneyBadger okay. Let it be [fid] than [sid] asc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have no duplicates, you can do:

```
select fid, sid
from t
where fid <= sid
union all
select fid, sid
from t
where fid > sid and
      not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.fid = t.sid and t2.sid = t.fid);
```

If you do have duplicates and don't care about the ordering, you can do:

```
select (case when fid < sid then fid else sid end) as sid,
       (case when fid < sid then sid else fid end) as sid
from t
group by (case when fid < sid then fid else sid end),
         (case when fid < sid then sid else fid end);
```

This could produce pairs that are not in the original data (because the inverse is in the data).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way that uses a left self-join that only keeps those without a match.

Example code:

```
declare @T table (fid int, [sid] int);

insert into @T (fid, [sid]) values
(1, 2),(1, 3),(1, 4),
(2, 1),(2, 3),(2, 4),
(3, 1),(3, 2),(3, 4);

select distinct t.fid, t.[sid]
from @T t
left join @T t2 on (t2.[sid] = t.fid and t2.fid = t.[sid] and t2.fid < t2.[sid])
where t2.fid is null
order by t.fid, t.[sid];
```

Result:

```
fid sid
1   2
1   3
1   4
2   3
2   4
3   4
```

Same result with a  NOT EXISTS:

```
select distinct fid, [sid]
from @T t
where not exists (
 select 1 from @T t2
 where t2.[sid] = t.fid and t2.fid = t.[sid] and t2.fid < t2.[sid]
)
order by fid, [sid];
```

Comment: seems like distinct is not needed.

Comment: Well, it's not needed with the example data. Just added it just in case.  If the real table has a unique combined index on (fid,sid) then that distinct would indeed be useless.  It's just example code anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Another aproach where ordering is available would be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [fid] ,[sid]

  FROM aaa where 

  CAST(fid AS VARCHAR(2) ) + '.'+ CAST(sid AS VARCHAR(2) ) not in 

  (SELECT DISTINCT CAST(sid AS VARCHAR(2) ) + '.'+ CAST(fid AS VARCHAR(2))

  FROM aaa)
```

Although this might not be recommended based on how many times you execute is and how much data will be processed.

Comment: Yeah. That might be not the best solution for me, there is more than 500 thousand records.